# iOS event propagation in UIViewController

Tags: ios, xamarin

I have a `UIViewController` that holds a `UIScrollView` and a custom `UIViewController` (let's call that `CustomVC`)

The `CustomVC` covers the ScrollView and has interaction enabled. On touch events how can I propagate the event back to the `UIScrollView`?

Comment: You can override a hit test within a view, but not a view controller as touch events propagate **down** from a view to each subviews, not up from a subview to each view parent. Instead of using a custom UIViewController via addChildViewController you might consider creating a custom UIView instead. Maybe more info would help clarify your goals using a child view controller

Comment: This is really helpful info. i think i'll do just that, create just a UIView instead. Im still not sure what the difference really is between a VC and just a view is. was under the impression that a VC should handle all the control logic and View is just for drawing

Comment: Here is the best (clearest) description of hit-testing on iOS I have ever seen, it has ObjC snippets of code that are easily converted to C#, but the diagrams and text descriptions are WAY BETTER then anything Apple has published @ http://smnh.me/hit-testing-in-ios/

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually send the event from CustomVC to the parent viewcontroller's view.